# php - add commas in the array

Tags: php

i have following array, and i have tried to add comma with the following code but i am not getting values its shows "array" only..

**Array Value**

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( 
   [0] => 144 [category_id] => 144 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [0] => 98 [category_id] => 98 ) 
   [2] => Array ( [0] => 146 [category_id] => 146 ) 
   [3] => Array ( [0] => 142 [category_id] => 142 )
)
```

**Tried code to display values with commas**

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $result_array);
echo $comma_separated;
```

**output i am getting**

```
Array,Array,Array,Array
```

please check what i am getting wrong

Comment: 144,98,146,142.....got the answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$comma_separated = implode(',', array_map(function($i) { return $i[0]; }, $result_array));
echo $comma_separated;
```